# Science fiction book or series with a character called a Vail or Vale, a tracker who hunts the main character through space

Tags: story-identification, space-travel

Looking for a book, or series of books, that had a character called a Vail or Vale that was basically a tracker and would kill the people tracked. When the person tracked was killed, the Vail started to assume their characteristics and started to realize that what they were doing was wrong.  Tracked the main character through space.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover/s?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 5):

In the Rings of the Master series by Jack Chalker the main characters have a nemesis called a Val (named after the flying dutchman IIRC) that pursues them. It is an agent of the all powerful computer created to save the human race (only a slight spoiler, please excuse me). This sounds like the story you are recalling

Comment: The Vals were named after Jean Valjean from Les Miserables. A point is made that they were named after the pursued character because they were imprinted with the fugitive's memories so that they could better track/capture them

Comment: Thanks @AlanT. It's been a while since I read them. Might dig them out and refresh my memories.